# Expanding Windows Paritions

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I'm in the process of removing an ubuntu partition from my laptop in favour of booting it from within windows - as I'd rather reclaim the space and only use ubuntu where necessary.

I've fixed the boot sequence so I don't have to worry about GRUB issues, now I'm onto fixing the space allocation, and I've run into two issues.

Firstly, I can't expand the C partition to include the former ubuntu partition (labelled V in this case). If I delete what is there the expand C option is greyed out, and trying to delete the partition entirely brings up an error about lack of memory free space.

Secondly, I'm trying to figure out what the random 3.85 GB on the end is for. I can see the recovery section on the far left, so why is there 3.85 GB chilling by itself?

I've added a screenshot to help illustrate my point /

[image: Space Allocation Screenshot]

Also note one of the sections in the top list refers to a repair disc that was in at the time of the screenshot.

Comment: Just as an aside, I suspect the 3.85GB may be an ubuntu recovery section? I'm not sure whether or not I set one up and may explain why windows doesn't recognise it.

Comment: You can edit your own question, and you should do that rather than adding information through comments.

Comment: Right, I'll bear that in mind as in other sections I've been asked to comment/answer instead of making large edits. As it was only a suggestion I felt it more appropriate to comment.

Comment: Certainly if you’re ***providing an answer***, you should post it as an answer.  And if you’re proposing large edits _to somebody else’s question_, you should probably stick to comments until your reputation is quite a bit higher.  But I’m surprised to hear that somebody has discouraged you from editing your own question.

Comment: To be fair, the edits I did before were alot larger than adding a few extra musings as I was here. In any case, I'll look to structure my questions a little better in future.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience Windows won't let you do much to the primary partition while booted to the primary partition. You might make use of Linux live-cd tools such as [Gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I agree that using a live CD is probably the way to go. Also, the 3.85GB partition is probably a Linux swap partition. A Linux live CD with GParted may clarify this issue, since GParted will be able to recognize more partition types (Linux filesystems, swap space, etc.) than will the standard Windows tool.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to say, I solved this.

I tried to use GParted for ages, but couldn't get the CD to boot properly.

Eventually took the plunge and deleted the 3.85GB. Tried to clear the free space and for some reason it now worked fine, and C: is up to ~450GB as hoped for.